# Malformed windows path environment variable

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, path

I haven't been able to find any information about this but my path environment variable has multiple entries that seem to be malformed.

Any idea what would have caused this?

```
F:\dev\emsdk;
F:\dev\emsdk\node\14.18.2_64bit\bin;
F:\dev\emsdk\upstream\emscripten;
/f/emsdk:
/f/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:
/f/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:
/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/c/Python310/Scripts/:
/c/Python310/:
/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:
/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:
/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:
/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:
/c/Windows/system32:
/c/Windows:
/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:
/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:
/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:
/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:
/c/Program Files/dotnet/:
C:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Program Files/nodejs/:
/c/HaxeToolkit/haxe:
/c/HaxeToolkit/neko:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Incredibuild:
/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/DDS Utilities:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Users/Username/emsd/k/c/Users/Username/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:
/c/Users/Username/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:
/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/c/Python310/Scripts/:
/c/Python310/:
/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:
/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:
/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:
/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:
/c/Windows/system32:
/c/Windows:
/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:
/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:
/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:
/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:
/c/Program Files/dotnet/:
C:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Program Files/nodejs/:
/c/HaxeToolkit/haxe:
/c/HaxeToolkit/neko:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Incredibuild:
/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/DDS Utilities:
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/:
/c/Python37/Scripts/:
/c/Python37/:
/c/Users/Username/Desktop/BCML/bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/Tools/WinNT:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/MSDev98/Bin:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/Tools:
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC98/bin:
/c/Ruby25-x64/bin:
/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:
/c/Users/Username/.dotnet/tools:
/c/Program Files (x86)/GitHub CLI/:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/npm:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin:
/c/tools/ghc-9.0.1/bin:
/c/tools/msys64:
/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/atom/bin:
```

```
F:\dev\emsdk;F:\dev\emsdk\node\14.18.2_64bit\bin;F:\dev\emsdk\upstream\emscripten;/f/emsdk:/f/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:/f/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Python310/Scripts/:/c/Python310/:/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/dotnet/:C:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/c/HaxeToolkit/haxe:/c/HaxeToolkit/neko:/c/Program Files (x86)/Incredibuild:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/DDS Utilities:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/c/Users/Username/emsd/k/c/Users/Username/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:/c/Users/Username/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Python310/Scripts/:/c/Python310/:/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:/c/Program Files/Eclipse Foundation/jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/dotnet/:C:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/c/HaxeToolkit/haxe:/c/HaxeToolkit/neko:/c/Program Files (x86)/Incredibuild:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/DDS Utilities:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/:/c/Python37/Scripts/:/c/Python37/:/c/Users/Username/Desktop/BCML/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/Tools/WinNT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/MSDev98/Bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Common/Tools:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC98/bin:/c/Ruby25-x64/bin:/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/c/Users/Username/.dotnet/tools:/c/Program Files (x86)/GitHub CLI/:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin:/c/tools/ghc-9.0.1/bin:/c/tools/msys64:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/atom/bin
```

Comment: try opening a fresh powershell window, run `$env:path -split ';'`, and see if the paths there are also malformed? Since only entries after emscripten are off, I think you can probably blame it. A brief search found a handful of old issues referencing that it does set environment variables (using `emsdk\emsdk_env.bat`), and can do it badly if configured wrong: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/issues/634

Comment: Are the forward-slashes causing any issue? Windows can interpret a  forward-slash as a standard back-slash, in most cases.  *However*, a **leading** slash is *verboten*, AFAIK. As to what caused that mess, it starts with Java, though I've not had an issue with Java installers. Possibly someone manually editing PATH?

Comment: I edited the post with the full path environment variable, I'm pretty sure it wasn't emscripten, as I had removed and installed it in a different location a few times and it shows up with the unix looking file paths in some other parts of it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not but it seems that only the user path is messed up, the system path seems completely fine.

Comment: Note that those are path expressions that git-bash or another mingw-like shell would use. and yes, the leading slash conforms to those standards.